# Symfony Form Collection with Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony-forms

Im using symfony 2.3. I want to make a form where the user can choose all the languages he speaks (the selectbox with the languages should be repeated with javascript, but thats not the problem here). I am happy if the selectboxes show up with the correct selections.

- I have the entities "Profile" and "Languages" with a unidirectional ManyToMany relation from Profile:foreign_languages to Languages. The generated table profile_has_languages looks o.k. I entered some testdata directly into it.
- I made a ProfileType and with $builder->add('foreign_languages') it shows me one select box with the correct languages selected. So far so good...

Now each selected languages should be in its own selectbox. I know that I need a collection:

```
$builder->add('foreign_languages', 'collection', array('type'=>new LanguageType()));
```

This is my LanguageType:

```
class LanguageType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
         $builder->add('name','entity',array(
                     'class'=>'Test\TestBundle\Entity\Languages',
                     'property' => "name",
                     'multiple' => false,
                     'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                         return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->orderBy('s.name', 'asc');
                       },
                ));
}
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'Test\TestBundle\Entity\Languages'));
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'language';
}
}
```

This gives me 3 selectboxes with all available languages (one box for each language the user has selected). Thats o.k., but the languages are all **unselected** - how can I preselect the correct languages now?

Do I have to use a loop somewhere? Or should there be a relation from Languages back to Profile (how would this look?)

I would really appreciate your help - I'm stuck with this since 2 days... :(

**Update**: I know how it works with a editable textfield from this example: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.
To simplify my question: what is difference if i want to show an entity as choice in my collection (selectable, but not editable)?

I found a working solution with a data transformer here: [Symfony 2 Embedded Form Collection Many to Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730544/symfony-2-embedded-form-collection-many-to-many?rq=1)

Is this the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

To persist those choice you'll need a many to many relationship between Profile and Language. Something like:

In Profil

```
/**
 * @var foreign_languages
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Language", mappedBy="profils")
 */
private $foreign_languages;
```

In Language

```
/**
 * @var profils
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profil", inversedBy="foreign_languages")
 */
private $profils;
```

But to pre-select options if the user hasn't chosen yet you'd have either to add the language entities to the entity you are using to create the form in your controller's method, or to add them directly when you are creating a new Profil.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not yet how to persist the selections. I entered some testdata by hand into the db, but these testselections are not shown when using a collection. I don't know if I have to preselect the saved selections in the entity or if I can get them "automatically" selected...